# leaflet on load wms tilelayer

Tags: jquery, backbone.js, leaflet, require

Is there a short way to see if a wms tilelayer has been loaded?
I know L.tileLayer.wms does not have any listeners. So at this point I need to add the wms layers to the map to be able to know if they are loaded.

This however slows down the webpage dramatically and there is no need to add them to the map if I know when they are loaded.

So this is what I have:

```
this.map.on('layeradd', function(data) {
    data.layer.on('load', function() {
        console.log('layer loaded');
    });
});

var water = L.tileLayer.wms(getGeoServer('wms', geoEnviroment), {
    layers: this.wmsLayer.name,
    format: 'image/png',
    opacity: 0,
    styles: '',
    transparent: true,
    attribution: ""
}).addTo(this.map);
```

But I would much rather like something like this:

```
 var water = L.tileLayer.wms(getGeoServer('wms', geoEnviroment), {
    layers: this.wmsLayer.name,
    format: 'image/png',
    opacity: 0,
    styles: '',
    transparent: true,
    attribution: ""
}).on('load', function() {
    console.log('layer loaded');
});
```

this way I do not need to load the layer to the map, but I know when the request to the server is done get the wms layer. After this I can question the layer.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "loading" a WMS layer - the layer never loads until you add it to the map. L.TileLayer.WMS is just a special case of a standard tile layer with the same events. It loads tiles as long as it is added to the map. Before adding it, there's no way of knowing what to load.

Comment: well ok that maybe answers my question. As long as you do a addTo(map) you are able to see if it is loaded on the map.
But there is no way to see if the data is set into the variable 'water' and maybe some first data is read by the script.

Comment: @BonifatiusK: you can watch variables in JS. Here you have [implementation](https://gist.github.com/eligrey/384583) and [usage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/watch#Examples).

Comment: Thanks for the info! seems like a handy tool to use. I will try to do some stuff with this.